# How can I see multiple specific todo-states in a custom agenda view without abusing org-agenda-skip-function?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, customize

I am trying to build a 'cleanup' agenda view, with a section for all tasks which are done and a review section for tasks in the `HOLD` or `WAITING` states. HOLD and WAITING are states I've defined as incomplete in

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '(
                      (sequence "TODO(t)" "NEXT(n)" "|" "DONE(d)")
                      (sequence "HABIT(x)" "WAITING(w@/!)" "HOLD(h@/!)" "|" "CANCELLED(c@/!)" "PHONE" "MEETING")))
```

I've tried to add a custom agenda command

```
("c" "Cleanup" ((todo '("WAITING" "HOLD")
```

etc, which I based off of the skip format, such as

```
(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("NEXT" "HABIT")))
```

which works fine. As a view definition though, this doesn't work. What is a good way to get a view of only the specific TODO states I want without manually skipping every other state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "|" as an OR operator when matching TODO states.  An agenda view of

```
("c" "Cleanup" todo "HOLD|WAITING")
```

will list all todo entries in the "HOLD" or "WAITING" states.  If you also want the more detailed matching of a `tags-todo` query you can use "/" to separate the todo states from the tag query or test the special "TODO" property with a regular expression

```
("c" "Cleanup" tags-todo "+sometag-badtag/HOLD|WAITING")
("c" "Cleanup" tags-todo "+sometag-badtag+TODO={HOLD\\|WAITING}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `org-agenda-skip-if` is the way to go.

You could combine it with `nottodo`, which, as you'd guess, is the inverse of `todo`.
That way you don't need to update your custom agenda manually when you alter the keyword sequence.

```
'(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
             'nottodo '("WAITING" "HOLD")))
```

See the documentation on `org-agenda-skip-if` for more details on possible arguments.